# MySQL order by very slow on joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to optimize the following query (it takes 40 seconds):

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE p.product_ID, p.title, p.slug, p.logo, ps.price, ps.sale_price
FROM products p
JOIN products_shops ps ON p.product_ID = ps.product_ID
WHERE p.status =  'active'
AND (
p.site =  '2'
OR p.site =  '3'
)
AND ps.sale_price <>  ''
AND ps.sale_price <>  '0'
AND ps.price <>  ''
AND ps.price <>  '0'
AND ps.sale_price <>  ''
AND ps.sale_price <>  '0'
GROUP BY p.product_ID
ORDER BY p.views DESC 
LIMIT 1060 , 20
```

MySQL Explain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e70YF.png

I have tried as subquery but takes even longer:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE p.product_ID, p.title, p.slug, p.logo, ps.price, ps.sale_price
FROM products_shops ps
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT product_ID, title, slug, views, logo FROM products 
  WHERE status =  'active'
  AND (site =  '2' OR site =  '3')
  ORDER BY views DESC
) p ON p.product_ID = ps.product_ID
WHERE (ps.sale_price <>  ''
AND ps.sale_price <>  '0'
AND ps.price <>  ''
AND ps.price <>  '0'
AND ps.sale_price <>  ''
AND ps.sale_price <>  '0')
LIMIT 1060 , 20
```

My indexes are:
`products` indexes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQkLJ.png

`products_shops` indexes: i.stack.imgur.com/UnnmQ.png

I also tried to make compound index on (product_ID, views) and drop views index but didn't help. `products` table has 600k rows, and `products_shops` has 740k rows.

When I remove ORDER BY from query it's really fast. I am unable to understand why it's slow despite the fact that `views` column is indexed.

Comment: Please provide the indexs on the product_shops table as well. Do you have an index on product_id in product_shops? From the name of the index in the explain you may do.

Comment: @AcyclicTau I have just added `products_shops` indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the conditions in your WHERE clause look to be on columns that do not have indexes. It maybe worth adding indexes to these columns. Neither of the following have indexes:

```
sale_price
price
```

An individual index on each should speed up the query.

Comment: Can't do that because a product might be available from 2 or more shops.

Comment: You had a key with product_id as the primary so that should work. Have updated the answer to suggest more indexes that might speed things up.

Comment: So from the explain you can see a 'filesort' being used, this is a good page to explain that http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: A compound index or two separate?

Comment: two seperate, but I don't think that will speed things up terrible. The performance hit is, I think, comming from the filesort being called as a result of the ORDER BY statement.

Comment: Even though I didn't expect it to work, it works! Now the result is returned in 1.47 seconds just by adding two separate indexes on sale_price & price columns. Thanks so much! Is there a way to make it even faster? Like 0.3s?